# Django can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'object'

Tags: python, django

Can anyone see the issues with this?

```
def is_valid(self, bundle, request=None):

    errors = {}
    # Check if user already exists before allowing API to create a new one.
    this_email = bundle.data.get('email', None)
    object.count = MemberParticipant.objects.filter(email=this_email).count()
    if object.count != 0:
         errors['Login']='Duplicate email address! A  participant with the ' \
                         'email address %s already exists.' % this_email
    return errors
```

I'm getting the following error:

**can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'object'**

I'm using a [Tastypie's custom validator](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validation.html)

Comment: Are you trying to use `object.count` as a single variable name? You can't mix dots into identifiers in Python without triggering attribute resolution - use something like `object_count` instead. As written you're trying to reassign the `count` attribute of the built in `object` class.

Comment: @Peter DeGlopper so sleepy, yes that was the issue! Would you like to add and answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use `object.count` as a single variable name? You can't mix dots into identifiers in Python without triggering attribute resolution - use something like `object_count` instead. As written you're trying to reassign the count attribute of the built in `object` class.